# Collection or Data Structure to hold other collections

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Is there a data structure that can store different types of collections? Assume I have the following collections:

```
ArrayList arrayL;
LinkedList linkedL;
Hashtable hashT;
```

I will be having multiple other collections(dont know how many yet) but I need a single data structure or some other collections store of all them. Because, In the end, I want to loop through it and empty each collection and use for another thing without having to create a new collection:

So Ideally: Let's my I have collection called UniversalCollection, then i can do:

```
for(Collections col : UniversalCollection){
  col.clear()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Getting a structure that store other collections like ArrayList,Maps,LinkedList etc..thanks

Comment: No, that's what you now think the solution is. What is the original problem? What are you going to use these collections for? What will you store in them?

Comment: Since the only common parent is `Object` you can't create such a collection either without losing type safety or without using `instanceof` (which sucks). So you should tell us what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe we can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Collection` objects to any of the existing data structures that you like. Just create an `ArrayList<Collection>`, for one example.

As mentioned in the comments, you can't add either a `Hashtable` or a `Map` directly to a list of `Collection` objects, but you can add the `entrySet` for each one as a work-around.

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
List list2 = new LinkedList();
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
Map map = new HashMap();

// add some data so we can see things get removed later
ht.put(new Object(), new Integer(1));
ht.put(new Object(), new Integer(2));
map.put(new Object(), new Integer(3));
map.put(new Object(), new Integer(4));

System.out.println(ht.size());
System.out.println(map.size());

Collection<Collection> coll = new ArrayList<Collection>();

coll.add(list1);
coll.add(list2);
coll.add(ht.entrySet());
coll.add(map.entrySet());

for(Collection c : coll) {
    c.clear();
}

System.out.println(ht.size());
System.out.println(map.size());
```

Since the set is backed by the map (or hash table) object, changes that you do to the set when you iterate over the collections are reflected in the map.

Comment: That was the first thing i did. Then I added a hashtable and IDE wanted me to cast it to a hashtable. In which case I could ass other tyoes of collections

Comment: Can you check this question?are you looking for this type of solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327077/interview-design-an-iterator-for-a-collection-of-collections

Comment: `Hashtable` is a member of the Collections framework: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: The problem with both `HashMap` and `Hashtable` is that they do not implement `Collection`.

Comment: You're both right :) Hashtable wasn't created as part of the collections framework but it was retro-fitted when collections were added.

Comment: *"they do not implement `Collection`"* .. or `Iterable`, so the only common parent is `Object`. So OP can't (nicely) do, what he likes to do.

Comment: You can do it but you'd have to put the `Map`'s `entrySet` in the universal collection rather than the `Map` itself.

Comment: @pbabcdefp This would work, yes, but looks kind of "smelly" :D.

Answer (score 0):

As all the objects you are creating are for sub classes of `Collection` class you can make use of an array of `Collection` for holding these objects.

Answer (score -1):

As your internal collections have different interfaces you can utilize the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Basically, create your own interface `Clearable` with single method `clear` and create it's implementations that wrap all desired `Collection` and `Map` interfaces.

So, you code will look like this:

```
    interface Clearable {
        void clear();
    }

    class CollectionClearable<T> implements Clearable {

        private Collection<T> col;

        public CollectionClearable(Collection<T> col) {
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            // process col
        }
    }

    class MapClearable<K, V> implements Clearable {

        private Map<K, V> col;

        public MapClearable(Map<K, V> col) {
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            // process col
        }
    }

    final class ClearableFactory {
        private ClearableFactory() {
        }

        static <K, V> Clearable create(Map<K, V> map) {
            return new MapClearable<K, V>(map);
        }

        static <T> Clearable create(Collection<T> col) {
            return new CollectionClearable<T>(col);
        }
    }
```

And finally you can do this:

```
    List<Clearable> clearables = Arrays.asList(
            ClearableFactory.create(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)),
            ClearableFactory.create(new HashMap<String, String>())
    );

    for (Clearable clearable : clearables) {
        clearable.clear();
    }
```

Also please note, that have concrete implementations of `Clearable` and factory to create them is not necessary. You can create anonymous class each time when you want to add another `Clearable` to the target collection and define it's `clear` logic on-fly.